# Question about the assumptions to have $G \simeq H\times K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I've been looking this fact:

> Let $G$ be a group, with $G$ abelian. Let $H$, $K \leq G$, with $G=HK$ and $H\cap K=\{e\}$. Then, we have that $G \simeq H\times K$.

And my question is:

> We know that $H,K\leq G \iff HK=KH$. Then, knowing that $G=HK$, it means that $G$ is abelian, and the assumption of being $G$ abelian is unnecessary, because it's implicit in $H,K\leq G$ and $G=HK$.

Am I wrong? Maybe I'm overlooking something.

Thanks.

Comment: does $\le$ denote normal subgroup?

Comment: No, only subgroup. $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$.

Comment: Say that $HK=KH$ is not $kh=hk$ but that for $kh$ there exist $h'$ and $k'$ such that $kh=h'k'$. The elements $k,k'$ and $h,h'$ can be all different.

Comment: @YotasTrejos, thank you! Put it as an answer :)

Comment: No, $H,K\le G\iff HK=KH$ is not true. Nor does $G=HK$ mean $G$ is abelian. Even if $G=HK=KH$, it doesn't mean $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To amplify on on Yotas's comment: look at $S_3$, the symmetries of an equilateral triangle. The subgroup generated by "flip about a median" has order 2; rotation has order 3. If these are $H$ and $K$, then $G = HK = KH$, but the elements of $K$ and $H$ do not commute, so $G$ is not abelian.

Hence your second highlighted paragraph is mistaken.